# how to add checkboxes in navigation drawer as a menu items in android with custom styles

Tags: android

I have created widgets_chkboxes file in layout
In menu create widgets.xml file

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:title="Filtered"/>
        <item android:title="SortedBy">
        <menu>
            <item
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widgets_checkboxes"
                android:title="Low To High"/>
            <item
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widgets_checkboxes"
                android:title="High To Low"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check2"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check3"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>

  </menu>
```

**Now you can set it in the code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_check);
    item.setChecked(isChecked);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_check) {
     if(item.isChecked());{
   // your code    or action 
  }


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```